# Open a Selenium browser with my cookies

Tags: ruby, selenium, firefox, cookies

I'm trying to create an automated script that goes to a website (Yik Yak) and submits stuff. It needs to access my cookies to know that I logged in before. It requires entering a key from my phone, and I can't automate that.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

profileDir = File.absolute_path("/home/carson/.mozilla/firefox/237ie3yd.default")
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name profileDir
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile

driver.navigate.to "https://www.yikyak.com/nearby/new"
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
element = driver.find_element(:class, 'form-control')
element.send_keys "Tessttt"
element.submit
```

It runs and opens Firefox, but it stops at the page where I have to enter the key my phone gets.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
default_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "default"
default_profile.native_events = true

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => default_profile)
```

Via [Ruby Bindings](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#using-an-existing-profile)